# Prove that $n^b \ll a^n$ as $n \to \infty$ Where $b > 0$ and $a > 1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I got a little stuck on this problem. My attempt was to try and prove it using $\log(n) \ll n^a$ as $n \to \infty$ because I have proven this before. I am not sure what is the best way to go about it. I tried to simplify with a log but never reached a clear conclusion.

e.g.

$\log(n^b) \ll \log(a^n)$, then $b\log(n) \ll n\log(a)$

Unsure which would be the best approach. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Notice that $$\frac{n \log a}{b \log n} = \frac{\log a}{b} \cdot \frac{n}{\log n}$$. What can you say about the limit of this quotient?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang This limit would go to infinity and therefore $n^b \ll a^n$ as $n \to \infty$  must be true. Thank you.